# Is there a difference between $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ and $GL(\Bbb F_p^n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the two groups isomorphic? While I see that $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ is the group of invertible matrices of size $n\times n$ with entries in $\Bbb F_p$ I don't really get what $GL(\Bbb F_p^n)$ is.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ in the latter?  Or, where have you seen it written that way?

Comment: No I mean $\Bbb F_p^n$ its elements are vectors of size $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$

Comment: The groups are isomorphic, but there isn't a natural isomorphism between them.  If you choose a basis for the underlying vector space, then there is an  isomorphism in terms of that basis.

Comment: But the multiplicative structure is all screwy so I'm not sure the "GL" part would make a ton of sense.

Comment: I guess it does when thinking about actions on vector spaces.   Never mind, I get what @lulu is saying now.

Comment: Recall for a $k$-vectorspace $V$, we write $GL(V)$ for the group of $k$-automorphisms of $V$.  Now $V=\mathbb{F}_p^n$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vectorspace...

Comment: I don't think @lulu is reading the question right. $\operatorname{GL}\left(\mathbb{F}_p^n\right)$ is the group of all endomorphisms of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space $\mathbb{F}_p^n$, while $\operatorname{GL}_n\left(\mathbb{F}_p\right)$ is the group of all invertible $n \times n$-matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$. These are isomorphic in a clear way, since $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ comes with a basis already chosen (it's not just a random $n$-dimensional vector space). Whether this isomorphism is "natural" depends on the categories you're working with -- it certainly is natural with respect to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are canonically isomorphic.  If $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, $GL(V)$ denotes the group of invertible linear maps $V\to V$.  If $V=k^n$, then linear maps $V\to V$ are represented by $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $k$ in the usual way, and so $GL(k^n)$ is isomorphic to the group $GL_n(k)$ of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $k$.